# MySQL merging query

Tags: php, mysql, view, union

I have to merge results of 2 queries like UNION does. My first query fetches few rows from a view based on some user selected criteria. Then I have to fetch records from second table using rows selected by first query. At last I have to merge 2 result sets in particular order.

I have tried to show table layouts and queries here

**First_Table**

```
First_Table_ID (Primary key)
col1
col2
col3
...
```

**Second_Table**

```
Second_Table_ID (Primary Key)
First_Table_ID (Foreign key to corresponding record in First table, allowed to be NULL also)
col1
col2
Col3
...
```

I have created a view as follows

```
    create view my_view (ID, item_typ, <oth_col_list>)
    as
        select First_Table_ID, item_typ, other_columns from First_Table 
        UNION ALL
        select Second_Table_ID, item_typ, other_columns_compatible_with_above_table from Second_Table 
where First_Table_ID is null;
```

**First query**

```
select * from my_view where <user_slected_criteria>
```

**Second query** 
    I am running through my PHP scripts using First_Table_ID from above resultset and it causes significant turnaroud time.

```
foreach(result_row){
    if(row belongs to First_Table) //decided based on item_typ which is different from both tables
        select * from Second_Table where First_Table_ID = result_row.ID
```

Display order is significant in this scenario and is as follows

Item1 from my_view

if any corresponding item in Second_Table show all

Item2 from my_view

if any corresponding item in Second_Table show all

...

Example data set I want to extract is as follows

First Table

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>First_Table_ID</th><th>Item_Typ</th><th>Date</th><th>Amt</th><th>Cust#</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>SVC</td><td>11/12/2015</td><td>10</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>SVC</td><td>11/20/2015</td><td>20</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>SVC</td><td>12/13/2015</td><td>40</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>SVC</td><td>4/1/2016</td><td>30</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Second Table

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Second_Table_ID</th><th>First_Table_ID</th><th>Item_Typ</th><th>Date</th><th>Amt</th><th>Cust#</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>PMT</td><td>11/15/2015</td><td>5</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>Discount</td><td>11/15/2015</td><td>5</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>PMT</td><td>11/25/2015</td><td>40</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>PMT</td><td>12/28/2015</td><td>35</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>Refund</td><td>12/30/2015</td><td>-15</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>NULL</td><td>PMT</td><td>1/1/2016</td><td>12</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>NULL</td><td>PMT</td><td>3/1/2016</td><td>35</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

View Output

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>Item_Typ</th><th>Date</th><th>Amt</th><th>Cust#</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>SVC</td><td>11/12/2015</td><td>10</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>SVC</td><td>11/20/2015</td><td>20</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>SVC</td><td>12/13/2015</td><td>40</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>SVC</td><td>4/1/2016</td><td>30</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>PMT</td><td>1/1/2016</td><td>12</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>PMT</td><td>3/1/2016</td><td>35</td><td>3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Final output after second table record are fetched for Item_Typ SVC from second Table All Second table

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Item_Typ</th><th>Date</th><th>Amt</th><th>Cust#</th><th>Balance</th></tr><tr><td>SVC</td><td>11/12/2015</td><td>10</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>PMT</td><td>11/15/2015</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>Discount</td><td>11/15/2015</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>SVC</td><td>11/20/2015</td><td>20</td><td>1</td><td>-5</td></tr><tr><td>PMT</td><td>11/25/2015</td><td>40</td><td>1</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>Refund</td><td>12/30/2015</td><td>-15</td><td>1</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>SVC</td><td>12/13/2015</td><td>40</td><td>1</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>PMT</td><td>12/28/2015</td><td>35</td><td>1</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>SVC</td><td>4/1/2016</td><td>30</td><td>1</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>PMT</td><td>1/1/2016</td><td>12</td><td>2</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>PMT</td><td>3/1/2016</td><td>35</td><td>3</td><td> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Some sample input and output records would be nice here.

Comment: what do you mean for if(item_typ belongs to First_Table) ... ?

Comment: You seem to be saying that you create a view combining data from your first and second tables, perform a query on that view & then in the result set only use the values from the first table. Why not just perform the original query on the first table alone? Or am I misunderstanding your pseudocode.

Comment: @CiroRa I have edited that part of code to be more specific.

Comment: @PaulF, I have edited part of view. Actually in view I am selecting those rows of second table which are not linked to first table (have null value for foreign key). In this case these tables actually represent services and payments against those services. Sometimes customers pay advance and such payments are stored in second table without a corresponding service in first table.

Comment: Still would be useful to see example input and expected results as Tim said.